# Can i patent mobile app algorithm

Tags: software, patent-applications, application, algorithms

We developing mobile app and we going to use device location which is generated by GPS or Mobile network in different way.Also we working on other system hardware data which is not currently using by others app like we doing.

So can i think about getting patent of our idea of using mobile location,camera and other hardware data in different way so other app can't copy our concept of our app.

There is other players in market who is using mobile device locations but our way of using location is very different from any other application.

**For example** Facebook using device location if google comes with an idea that we can use location in unique way so can google file for patent for how they going to use device location.

Comment: If you do not have the resources now to hire a patent attorney then you might consider starting a bounty since you now have enough points.  You will likely get an answer that pleases you.  If not then you might save some money by NOT hiring an attorney prematurely.

Comment: ฉันไม่ทราบในข้อกฎหมายถึงไม่ได้คิดถึงผลเสียครับ

Comment: I am still waiting for the concrete answer.Crossed my fingers i hope some expert will give their views on this

Answer (score 1):

If your idea is novel and non obvious, you can consider filing a patent. It is probably a good idea to search for patents of the other players you mention and try to find other prior art. If you still think your idea is patentable, the next step is to discuss this with a patent lawyer. Doing your own prior art search and providing a detailed written description of the idea will make working with an attorney more efficent.

Comment: Agreed. Time to seek legal help.

Comment: In any case, it helps to do a prior art search and to write up a thorough description of the invention. These make discussions with a patent attorney more efficient.